How to best set value of identity sequence for GENERATE BY DEFAULT column when supplying identity value when inserting?
I have a table with an identity column that generates by default. I need to be able to write specific values to the identity column due to logically replicating the table, so hence why using GENERATE BY DEFAULT.
However, when identity values are set in the INSERT statement, the identity sequence value isn't updated so could lead to duplicate values being attempted to be inserted for the identity field for later INSERTs where the value isn't supplied and instead is generated by the sequence.
What is the best way to update the sequence value in this instance?
Or am I going about this completely wrong?

why not use a generated additional column, where you implement your logic

could lead to duplicate values being attempted to be inserted - have you tried to see if this actually happens? I'm assuming that you have a UNIQUE index (or PK) on this field?
